# django loop with subclass

Tags: c++, python, html, django

Hi I am using C++ and I have written a wrapper in python.  Here is a snippet of my code.

```
for day in Times:
    for item in day.data():
       print "%d: %d-%d" % (day.key(), item.key(), item.data() )
```

Is there any way in which I can short circuit this so I can do.

```
print Times[0].data()[0].key()
```

Comment: You'll have to be more specific.  You're asking help using some custom types written in C++ with Python bindings without telling us what this type is or what bindings you're using...

Comment: So you just want to print one `"%: %d-%d"` string instead of all of them? Oh, and is there some C++ question I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way in which I can short circuit this so I can do.

Not necessarily.

In `for day in Schedule:` the value of `day` is not an index from 0 to `len(Schedule)`.  Day is the first element in the `Schedule` collection.

Without knowing what kind of collection `Schedule` is, it's impossible to say what index scheme would get the "first" item from the collection.

If `Schedule` is a set, for example, you can do something like `Schedule.pop()` to get the first element that would have been assigned to `day`.  But that has a side-effect of updating `Schedule`, so it's not really going to work.

If `Schedule` is a dictionary, then, you can try something like `Schedule.key()[0]` to get the first value that would have been assigned to `day`.

If `Schedule` is a sequence, then `day` should be equal to `Schedule[0]`.